# OS.system- adding the output of OS .system output command to the command of another os system command

Tags: python-2.x, data-analysis, emc

I can use only python 2.6.6 and subprocess is not working so I need to use only os module
Below is the program

```
import os 

server = raw_input("server name:")
var = "symaccess -sid 239 list -type init | grep \"{0}\"".format(server)
wwn = os.system(var)
init = 'symaccess -sid 239 -type init show {0}'.format(wwn)
print init
os.system(init)
```

above is the script I used to add an output of one `os.system` to another `os.system`, I got the first `os.system` executed but for the second one i.e `os.system(unit)` is not coming because the output of `os.system(var)` should be assigned to a variable to `wwn`. could someone tell how to assign a variable to `os.system(init)`

Here in this script, the output of var says some `X` should be assigned to own but it's not taking `X` it's taking it as `0`. So need your help to sort this why it is taking zero instead of `X`. Finally this `X` should be placed at `init` variable at `{0}`.

Comment: What do you mean `subprocess` is not working? Both `os.system` and `os.popen` are depreciated since Python 2.6 in favor of the `subprocess` module and you should be using it instead.

Comment: I dont know but whenever iam using the subprocess it is throwing error like no modules like tht.so any chamce that we can get this using OS module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.system` does *not* return the output of the command - it returns the errorlevel.

If you need command output, use

```
wwn = os.popen(var).read()
```

That will assign the output from command `var` to `wwn`.

Be warned - the output is returned completely, with the trailing newline. You might want to `strip()` it before using it.